# Magento 2 Braintree Card Payment integrate with react native app

Tags: php, react-native, magento

I try to use Braintree Card Payment extension from **Magento 2**, but I can't find a solution. If I use card payment from magento web theme, it works fine, but if I make endpoint requests from Postman I receive the following error message:

```
Transaction has been declined. Please try again later.
```

I use magento 2 endpoinds:

```
/rest/V1/carts/mine/shipping-information and /rest/V1/carts/mine/payment-information
```

I read that if you want to integrate braintree card payment for native mobile app (frontend), you need to create a custom module programatically on backend.

Someone else has done this and can help me with an implementation or some steps to follow?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Share the relevant code snippets you have tried so far.

Comment: I [edited your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing), improving either its formatting, or [its quality](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/02/05/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/) to help people understanding your question, and to help you to get an appropriate answer.
But you still may need to add further information for your question to become fully solvable.